# Converting jpg to greyscale

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to convert an image to greyscale as part of a set of instructions I'm following. However, it won't let me save after making it greyscale.

Error:

```
    img2.save("img.jpg")
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1698, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py", line 586, in _save
    raise IOError("cannot write mode %s as JPEG" % im.mode)
IOError: cannot write mode LA as JPEG
```

Code:

```
img = Image.open(fname)
img2 = img2.convert('LA')
img2.save("img.jpg")
```

Answer (score 10):

LA is L (8-bit pixels, black and white) with **ALPHA**.  JPEG images do not support the alpha(transparency) channel, choose GIF or PNG instead.

Or try

```
img2 = img.convert('L')
```

For 8 bit black and white only

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
img2 = img.convert('LA').convert('RGB')
```

Comment: could you please explain why converting to RGB solved this issue?